# Find Arbitrage with graph theory

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve this problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/arbitrage

> If you are going to travel to the World Finals, you cannot rely on
>   Czech Crowns. You would have to exchange your money for various
>   foreign currencies. This problem deals with multiple currencies and
>   their exchange rates. Your task is to verify that some set of exchange
>   rates is safe, namely detect a possibility of so-called arbitrage.
>
> An arbitrage is a risk-free combination of buy and sell operations
>   that gains profit from imbalance in market prices. The prices may
>   apply to various things, typically stock exchange but also currencies.
>
> Input The input consists of several test cases. Each case begins with
>   a line containing one positive integer number , 1≤≤200, the number
>   of currencies.
>
> The second line of each test case contains  currency codes separated
>   by a space. Each code is composed of 3 uppercase letters and all codes
>   in one test case are different.
>
> The third line contains one integer number ,0≤≤⋅(−1), the
>   number of exchange rates available. Each of the following  lines
>   contains one exchange rate in the following format: first currency
>   code, space, second currency code, space, integer number , colon
>   (’:’), and integer number . The meaning is as follows: If you pay
>    units of the first currency, you will get  units of the
>   second currency. You may assume that 1≤,≤100 and that the two
>   currencies are different.
>
> The last test case is followed by a line with =0.

My approach is to do a dfs rooted at every node, checking if there's a cycle whose product is bigger than 1.

This runs in `O(n^2)`.

Is there a faster solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, this problem has two measures of input size; C is the number of currencies and R is the number of exchange rates available. The "brute-force" solution of using DFS from every currency is O(C² + CR), where in general R can be up to O(C²) itself.

The problem can be modelled as finding a negative-weight cycle in a graph. The nodes are the currencies, the edges are the exchange-rate pairs, and the edge weight is `-log(r)` for an exchange rate `r`. Using negative logarithms means the sum of weights for a cycle is negative if and only if the product of the exchange rates is greater than 1.

Finding a negative-weight cycle is usually achieved by adapting a standard shortest-path algorithm, such as [Bellman-Ford](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/finding-negative-cycle-in-graph.html#toc-tgt-0) in O(CR) time, or [Floyd-Warshall](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/finding-negative-cycle-in-graph.html#toc-tgt-2) in O(C³) time. Neither of these is asymptotically better than your solution in the case that R is O(C) or greater, but it may be worth benchmarking to see if an alternative is faster in practice.

Comment: Actually, I just realized a dfs-based approach would be n^3 :)  I have to maintain a copy of all nodes visited in a given path - that's O(n).

Comment: Each run of DFS takes O(C + R) time, and you're doing DFS for each of C nodes, hence O(C² + CR). This is O(C³) in the case that R is O(C²); in that case, Bellman-Force is also O(C³). It doesn't take asymptotically more time or space to keep track of the sequence of nodes in the cycle in DFS.

Comment: I am not sure if each dfs run takes O(C + R) time in this case. My goal with the dfs is to check that, if I start at vertex u, I can cycle back to u. For each path rooted at u, I will have to maintain a set of all nodes I have seen thus far in that path. Maintaing that set is O(n)

Comment: Each run of DFS does take O(C + R) time, whether or not you record the visited nodes in a set. I don't know whether you are using n to mean the number of currencies or the number of exchange-rate pairs, but adding an additional O(C) or O(R) time and space to an algorithm which is O(C + R) time and space does not change the complexity.